# Exponential (exp) function in C - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I use this code, but get an segmentation error. What is wrong here ?

GNU nano 2.2.6                                                        File: taak8.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

double recursie(double som,double oud, double x, int stap){
    double y = oud*x/stap;
    if(y >= 1/1000){
            return recursie(som+y,y,x,stap++);
    } else {
            return som;
    }
}

double exp(double x){
    return recursie(1,1,x,1);
}

int main(){
    double inp;
    scanf("%lf",&inp);
    printf("your result %lf",exp(inp));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a start, stop using post-increment or even pre-increment. The operators have very limited applicability. In this case you need to pass `stap+1`!

Comment: Pay attention to the name of this web site.

Answer (score 4):

`if(y >= 1/1000)` problem is there. `1/1000` will always be `0`. so put `0` there directly.

But i think you wanted to do this below , try this instead

`if(y >= 1.0/1000)`

and this also

```
recursie(som+y,y,x,++stap);
```

use `++stap` to increment stap instead of `stap++`.Because you have to send the incremented value of `stap` to recursive function call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment your step **before** you call the recursive step, not after. In other words, you need to use pre-increment, not post-increment:

```
return recursie(som+y,y,x,stap+1);
```

Comment: That's still a bad idea. Modifying `stap` is pointless and obscures what is actually going on. Pass `stap+1`.